eventlistener handleUnload not being called in React
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import GlobalStyles from '@mui/material/GlobalStyles';
import Info from '../../info'

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#1976d2',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#42a5f5',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
    },
});

const globalStyles = {
    td: {
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        maxWidth: 200,
    },
    '.dialog-content': {
        fontSize: '0.9rem',
    },
};

const DataWindow = ({ data, context, onClose }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const path = `/info/${context}/info?id=${data.id}`;
        const windowName = `${context}: ${data.name}`;
        const newWindow = window.open(path, windowName, "width=800,height=400");

        if (newWindow) {
            newWindow.document.title = `${context}: ${data.name}`;
            newWindow.document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';

            const container = newWindow.document.createElement('div');
            newWindow.document.body.appendChild(container);

            const handleUnload = () => {
                onClose();
                newWindow.close();
            };

            newWindow.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload);

            const root = createRoot(container);
            let isUnmounted = false;

            if (!isUnmounted) {
                root.render(
                    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                        <CssBaseline />
                        <GlobalStyles styles={globalStyles} />
                        <Info rcId={data.id} />
                    </ThemeProvider>
                );
            }

            return () => {
                isUnmounted = true;
                newWindow.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload);
            };
        }
    }, [data, context, onClose]);

    return null;
};

export default DataWindow;

I am opening the window and it opens properly, and it gets redirected to the path which renders all the information inside the window. Now in my parent file,
  const handleInfoClick = (rowData) => {
    console.log("OPEN WINDOW");
    setSelectedRowData(rowData);
    setIsPopupOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClosePopup = () => {
    console.log("CLOSE WINDOW");
    setIsPopupOpen(false);
  };

<DataWindow
    data={selectedRowData}
    context="rc"
    onClose={handleClosePopup}
/>

When I open the window OPEN WINDOW appears in the console, when I close the window CLOSE WINDOW does not appear. If I remove the path and keep it empty.
const newWindow = window.open('', windowName, "width=800,height=400");
Then when I repeat the opening and closing process CLOSE WINDOW appears on the console.
I am confused why is the handleUnload being called when there is no path and not being called when there is a path.
